# how to share post with react-native-fbsdk GraphRequest

Tags: react-native, facebook-graph-api

I want to put automatic sharing post on facebook feature in react native. I have tried to do with react-native-fbsdk GraphRequest , but its not working.

I have tried to read facebook graph api documentation but I did not get exact idea how can implement in my application.

If anyone have done this feature then please help.

my code

```
postToFacebook = () => {
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
      (data) => {
        let postId = data.userID;
        console.log(data, "test... 6")
        try {
          let tempAccesstoken = data.accessToken;
          console.log(tempAccesstoken, "test... 1");

          const _responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
            console.log(result);
          }

          const postRequestParams = {
            message: {
              string: "Hello world!"
            }
          }

          const postRequestParams = {
            'link': { 'string': 'www.google.com' }
          }

          const postRequestConfig = {
            httpMethod: "POST",
            version: "v2.9",
            parameters: postRequestParams,
            accessToken: tempAccesstoken
          }

          console.log(postRequestConfig);

          const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
            "/me/feed",
            postRequestConfig,
            _responseInfoCallback,
          );

          new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error, "test... 5")
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to share some posts on your feed?

Comment: yes I want post on feed

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next#share-api)

Comment: I have already tried this , this ShareApi is not present in 'react-native-fbsdk-next'.